# unarchiveObject(with:) was deprecated in iOS 12.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function to save a HTTPCookie between app restarts (which I found on some website):

```swift
static fileprivate func loadCookieProperties(from data: Data) -> [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]? {
    let unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
    return unarchivedDictionary as? [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]
}
```

The issue is that the post I found was from 2018 and uses deprecated code. I get this warning:

> 'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead

I have tried searching for that error but all the answers are from 2019 and converts to other functions which are also deprecated.

Any ideas on how to convert this 2 line Swift function so I don't use stuff deprecated in iOS 12?

Thanks!

EDIT:

The linked answer to the question this was marked as a duplicate of doesn't work for me. I found this when searching but couldn't get it to work. Here's what I tried:

```swift
let unarchivedDictionary = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
  ofClasses: [NSArray.self, Dictionary.self], from: data) as! [Dictionary]
```

Errors:

- Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>.Type' to expected element type 'Array.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'any AnyObject.Type')
- Generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred
- Generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred in cast to 'Array'

```swift
let unarchivedDictionary = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
  ofClass: Dictionary.self, from: data)
```

Errors:

- Generic parameter 'Key' could not be inferred
- Generic parameter 'Value' could not be inferred
- Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' conform to 'NSCoding'
- Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' inherit from 'NSObject'

```swift
let unarchivedDictionary = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
  ofClass: [HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any].self, from: data)
```

Errors:

- Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]' conform to 'NSCoding'
- Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[HTTPCookiePropertyKey : Any]' inherit from 'NSObject'

So I'll rephrase my question a bit:

How is the solution suggested in the hint and in the answers to other similar questions actually applied the my specific code example? I just can't crack this nut.

Comment: Did you tried what the message says, using Dictionary.self for class parameter ?